# Kubernetes pod and service not showing in prometheus target

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have deployed prometheus 2.0 on my multi node kubernetes cluster made from kubeadm. While accessing the prometheus dashboard i am not able to view pods and service job even after configuring it in prometheus configuration yaml file.
prometheus target are as follow https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiQPG.png .
Does this problem has anything to do with the prometheus version. I think i am going wrong with the syntax part of the configuration.

```css
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  evaluation_interval: 5s
scrape_configs:
- job_name: kubernetes-apiservers
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: null
    role: endpoints
    namespaces:
      names: []
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    insecure_skip_verify: false
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: default;kubernetes;https
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
- job_name: kubernetes-nodes
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: null
    role: node
    namespaces:
      names: []
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    insecure_skip_verify: false
  relabel_configs:
  - separator: ;
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
    replacement: $1
    action: labelmap
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics
    action: replace
- job_name: kubernetes-pods
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: null
    role: pod
    namespaces:
      names: []
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    insecure_skip_verify: false
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    separator: ;
    regex: "true"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    separator: ;
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: $1:$2
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
    replacement: $1
    action: labelmap
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
- job_name: kubernetes-cadvisor
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: null
    role: node
    namespaces:
      names: []
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    insecure_skip_verify: false
  relabel_configs:
  - separator: ;
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
    replacement: $1
    action: labelmap
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
    action: replace
- job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints
  scrape_interval: 5s
  scrape_timeout: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: null
    role: endpoints
    namespaces:
      names: []
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    separator: ;
    regex: "true"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
    separator: ;
    regex: (https?)
    target_label: __scheme__
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    separator: ;
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: $1:$2
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
    replacement: $1
    action: labelmap
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: kubernetes_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
```

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the configuration here instead of linking a picture. Besides that: What Prometheus queries did you try?

Comment: When i am hitting " http://172.30.20.78:32343/api/v1/query_range?query=container_memory_usage_bytes{job="kubernetes-pods"}&start=2017-12-14T16:36:51.781Z&end=2017-12-14T23:42:51.781Z&step=1h
 "
 .I am  not getting any data. Just result is success coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are doing the query you posted in the comments:

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{job="kubernetes-pods"}
```

This doesn't work, because you are filtering by the job name `kubernetes-pods`, but `container_memory_usage_bytes` comes from cAdvisor. So according to your config the job is named `kubernetes-cadvisor`.

Therefore this should work:

```
container_memory_usage_bytes{job="kubernetes-cadvisor"}
```

Since the series name is rather unique, you can just omit the job name:

```
container_memory_usage_bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.So are you saying that pods metric data like (memory,CPU,etc) will be given by kubernetes-cadvisor job?.

Comment: Yes. From the [project description](https://github.com/google/cadvisor): "Analyzes resource usage and performance characteristics of running containers."

Comment: Ok got it.Thanks.